# Implement monkehTweets on Coldfusion Server

Tags: twitter, coldfusion

I've inherited a site running Coldfusion, and I'm trying to get a twitter feed on the site. I've found a tool that seems to do the job, and I've registered my app with Twitter and I have my client and OAuth codes.

The problem is that I'm not familiar enough with Coldfusion to know exactly what code I need to put on the page in question to pull the tweets. This is the library I'm using: https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/monkehTweets

From what I can gather, my code should look something like this:

```
<cfinvoke 
 component = "component_name" 
 method="method_name" 
 returnvariable="return_variable">
 <cfinvokeargument name="arg1" value="value">
 <cfinvokeargument name="arg2" value="value">
</cfinvoke>
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what to put in any of those fields. There doesn't seem to be a list anywhere of the arguments OR what you should put in the name, method, and variable fields. All I need is to pull three recent tweets. This probably isn't a standard format for questions on here, but any help from someone who knows Coldfusion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure to read the monkehTweets_readMe.pdf which you can find in the installation folder of the package. More information and useful links can be found here: http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/monkehtweets-coldfusion-twitter-cfc-update.

Comment: I vaguely recall there may have been an update to the monkehtweets package which addressed connecting to the updated twitter api/oauth.

Comment: @AndreasSchuldhaus I have everything working correctly as far as my connections go. My problem lies in my ineptitude with Coldfusion. I am familiar with the basics (cfincludes, cfif/else, etc.) but I have never used a cfc file before. When it comes to actually outputting the tweets, what is the code that I should be putting into my .cfm file? I read all the documentation, but I was unable to find anything like, "If you want to get a stream of recent tweets, add <cfsomething>codecodecode</cfsomething> where you want them to appear."

Comment: OK, so your question is more "how do I use CFCs in ColdFusion", to which the answers are probably gonna be - quite legitimately - RTFM, I'm afraid. All of CFML, as well as a lot of guidance as to how to use CFCs are in the online docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fec.html. I recommend you back away from this particular task, and focus on getting up to speed with CFML first.

Comment: Well, this is a freelance gig, so I don't plan on trying to ingest an entire language to learn how to put style-able tweets on a site. If worst comes to worst I can use the Twitter widgets. I understand the basics of the CFC, I was just surprised that there didn't seem to be any list of the functions specific to this library anywhere in the documentation for monkehTweets. I'll probably keep messing around with it, but if anyone has an example of how they used this on their site, that would be awesome.

Comment: Hi paperbeatsscissors. I wrote monkehTweets and can help you off list to resolve your issue - it doesn't appear to be a question for StackOverflow, and i'm more than happy to help you. One bit of advice I'd offer first, though, is to look through the code in the monkehTweet package. The actual monkehTweet.cfc object is heavily commented with hint attributes for all arguments / parameters required to send values to the API. If you need help actually outputting data, drop me a line via the comment form on my site and I'll help you via email. Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have written a very basic demo to pull out and display information from the authenticated user's timeline.

You need to start with the object instantiation, which it appears you have done: (obviously adding your own OAuth / Twitter details to the **init** method here)

```
<cfset objmonkehTweet   =   new monkehTweet.com.coldfumonkeh.monkehTweet(
            consumerKey     =   '',
            consumerSecret      =   '',
            oauthToken      =   '',
            oauthTokenSecret    =   '',
            userAccountName     =   '',
            parseResults        =   true
        ) />
```

Setting the **parseResults** value to true will convert the response into a struct or XML object that you can dump in ColdFusion and easily read the values.

Next, make a call to the **getUserTimeline()** method. If we don't pass any user id or screen name values in to the method call, it will access the timeline for the authenticated user:

```
<cfset arrStatus = objMonkehTweet.getUserTimeline() />
```

As no parameters were sent in regarding format, monkehTweet will return the default response as JSON (which, with **parseResults** set to true, will result in an array of structs).

Now we can start creating the loop. This is *very* basic, but will help you get up and running.

Define the maximum number of tweets to return:

```
<cfset totalTweets = 3 />
```

It's prudent to then check the length of the array (just in case we have less than the desired maximum number of results):

```
<cfif arrayLen(arrStatus) LT totalTweets>
    <cfset totalTweets = arrayLen(arrStatus) />
</cfif>
```

Now define a loop, starting at 1 with a maximum of the **totalTweet** value:

```
<cfoutput>
<ul>
<cfloop from="1" to="#totalTweets#" index="tweet">

    <cfset status = objMonkehTweet.entify(arrStatus[tweet]) />      
    <li>#arrStatus[tweet]['user']['name']#: #status#</li>

</cfloop>
</ul>
```

You can now access each specific tweet like so: **arrStatus[tweet]**.
The monkehTweet object contains a helper function called **entify** which will convert any URLs, user mentions and hashtags into HTML URLs for display. Simply pass in the tweet object and it will return the formatted status for you. You can also reference any object within the response directly, as we have here with the user name value.

To see what is being returned, it's always best to dump out the entire response so that you can see what is available to access and use in your display:

```
<cfdump var="#arrStatus#" />
```

I hope that helps get you up and running.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! This is exactly what I was trying to do! Really appreciate the detailed response. I wish I could give this 1,000 upvotes.