# Issues with monkehTweets and ColdFusion

Tags: twitter, coldfusion

I am trying to display the latest tweets from an account on a website through the  [MonkehTweets component](https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/monkehTweets). I am pretty much following the accepted answer here: [Implement monkehTweets on Coldfusion Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285984/implement-monkehtweets-on-coldfusion-server).

I created the Twitter App, generated all the necessary tokens, and uploaded the CFCs to my website. I am then trying out this (keys obviously filled out in my code):

```
<cfset application.objMonkehTweet = new com.coldfumonkeh.monkehTweet(
    consumerKey = '',
    consumerSecret = '',
    oauthToken = '',
    oauthTokenSecret = '',
    userAccountName = 'evagorasc',
    parseResults = true
    ) />

<cfset mytweets = application.objMonkehTweet.getUserTimeline(
    count="1",
    checkHeader=true
    ) />

<cfdump var="#mytweets#" />
```

No matter what I do though I get the following CFDUMP result. This error looks more like a missing certificate in CF when calling secure apps. Any ideas?

```
struct
Charset  [empty string]
ErrorDetail  I/O Exception: peer not authenticated
Filecontent  Connection Failure
Header   [empty string]
Mimetype     Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Responseheader  struct [empty]
Statuscode   Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
Text     YES
struct [empty]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday, I came across this issue. I googled a lot and read many blogs to find the solutino for this issues, but not found the exact answer. Miguel-F explain it but its not resolve the issue. Here are the steps that I am going to listed down. It will surely solve the issue.

My Development Environment specification: 
Windows 7 Ultimate, XAMPP 1.7.7, Coldfusion 9 and using the lastest monkehTweet CFC

**Step 1**

Open The URL in Firefox (https://api.twitter.com)

I can't insert the picture due the the reputation, as I got the reputation, i will sure insert it.

**Step 2**

Save Click on the More Information and then click View Certification
Then click on Detail Tab, click on the Export button and save the file with twitter.cer

Open Run tool and run the command 'cmd' to open command prompt

Now We need to install twitter certification in Coldfusion 9.

in my case to install the certification, I use the following command

```
C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin>keytool -import -v -keystore cacert -alias twitter_cert -storepass mypass -file c:/twitter.cer
```

it will ask to install then enter yes

to confirm the certification for listing in java keystore. You need to use following command.

```
C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore cacert -alias twitter_cert -storepass mypass
```

it will surely list the certification.

Now you need to restart the Coldfusion 9 Application from Service manager.

Step 3:

Now, you need to do to open base.cfc in monkehtweet folder

Find the function httpOAuthCall and change with following code

```
<cffunction name="httpOAuthCall" description="Allows Scripting of CFHTTP" access="private" output="false" returntype="Struct">
        <cfargument name="url"          type="string"   displayname="url"       hint="URL to request"       required="true" />
        <cfargument name="method"       type="string"   displayname="method"    hint="Method of HTTP Call"  required="true" />
        <cfargument name="parameters"   type="struct"   displayname="method"    hint="HTTP parameters"      required="false" default="#structNew()#" />
            <cfset var returnStruct = {} />

                <cfif structKeyExists(arguments.parameters,'params')>
                    <cfset structAppend(arguments.parameters,arguments.parameters['params']) />
                    <cfset structDelete(arguments.parameters,'params') />
                </cfif>
                <cfset objSecurity = createObject("java", "java.security.Security") />
                <cfset storeProvider = objSecurity.getProvider("JsafeJCE") />
                <cfset objSecurity.removeProvider("JsafeJCE") />


                <cfhttp url="#arguments.url#" method="#arguments.method#" result="returnStruct" multipart="true">
                    <cfif structKeyExists (arguments.parameters,'media[]') and arguments.method is 'POST'>
                        <cfhttpparam type="file" file="#arguments.parameters['media[]']#" name="media[]" />
                    </cfif>

                    <!--- Strip out the non-required parameters (the custom monkehTweet arguments) --->
                    <cfset structDelete(arguments.parameters,'checkHeader', false) />
                    <cfset structDelete(arguments.parameters,'format', false) />
                    <cfset structDelete(arguments.parameters,'media[]', false) />

                    <cfif arguments.method is 'POST'>
                        <cfloop collection="#arguments.parameters#" item="local.key">
                            <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="#key#" value="#arguments.parameters[key]#" />
                        </cfloop>
                    </cfif>
                </cfhttp>

                <cfset objSecurity.insertProviderAt(storeProvider, 1) />
        <cfreturn returnStruct />
    </cffunction>
```

Now, run your example, with all your keys provided and it will surely work.

Answer (score 3):

*Here is a previous answer that I have given on how to install certificates for ColdFusion and how to retrieve the certificates using Internet Explorer.*

Here are the steps you need to perform in order to install the certificate to the Java keystore for ColdFusion. First, be sure you are updating the correct cacerts file that ColdFusion is using. In case you have more than one JRE installed on that server. You can verify the JRE ColdFusion is using from the administrator under the 'System Information'. Look for the Java Home line.

> The default truststore is the JRE's cacerts file. This file is typically located in the following places:
>
> - **Server Configuration:**
>
>   cf_root/runtime/jre/lib/security/cacerts
> - **Multiserver/J2EE on JRun 4 Configuration:**
>
>   jrun_root/jre/lib/security/cacerts
> - **Sun JDK installation:**
>
>   jdk_root/jre/lib/security/cacerts
> - Consult documentation for other J2EE application servers and JVMs

In order to install the certificate you need to first get a copy of the certificate. This can be done by using Internet Explorer. *Note that different versions of Internet Explorer will behave slightly differently but should be very similar to these steps. For example, earlier versions of IE might save the certificate under a different tab than I mention.*

1. Browse to the SSL URL in Internet Explorer - `https://api.twitter.com/`.
2. View the certificate by clicking on the *lock icon* and clicking view certificate
3. Then click the Install Certificate... button (note: if you do not see this button you must close IE and run it as administrator first)
4. Click on IE's Internet Options and click the Content tab
5. Click the Certificates button
6. Find the server's certificate under the Intermediate Certification Authorities tab, select the cert and click the Export... button
7. Export using DER format

Copy the exported certificate file to your ColdFusion server (you can delete the cert from IE if you want)

1. Run `cmd` prompt as administrator on the ColdFusion server
2. Make a backup of the original cacerts file in case you run into issues

> The keytool is part of the Java SDK and can be found in the following places:
>
> - **Server Configuration:**
>
>   cf_root/runtime/bin/keytool
> - **Multiserver/J2EE on JRun 4 Configuration:**
>
>   jrun_root/jre/bin/keytool
> - **Sun JDK installation:**
>
>   jdk_root/bin/keytool
> - Consult documentation for other J2EE application servers and JVMs

To install the cert:

1. Change directory to your truststore's location (where the cacerts file is located)
2. Type this command  (use current jvm and use current jvm's keytool) `"c:\program files\java\jre7\bin\keytool" -import -v -alias your_cert_alias_name -file C:\wherever_you_saved_the_file\cert_file.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit`
3. Type yes at the prompt to "Trust this certificate?"

Note: *your_cert_alias_name* I used above can be whatever you want
Note: *C:\wherever_you_saved_the_file\cert_file.cer* change these values to whatever you use for the server folder and certificate file name

To verify the cert:

1. Type this command  (use current jvm and use current jvm's keytool) `"c:\program files\java\jre7\bin\keytool" -list -v -keystore cacerts -alias your_cert_alias_name -storepass changeit`

Note: *your_cert_alias_name* use the same name here that you used above to install the cert

**Restart the ColdFusion service** It will not read the updated cacerts file until you do this.

You can delete the imported certificate file from the server if you wish.

Comment: Your instructions were spot on. I managed to install the certificate and verified that I can make a simple HTTPS request fine. Calling the component still produces the same error though, and I am looking to see what's up with that.

Comment: Well glad that my answer helped, but I don't know why you are still getting the same error. Are you sure that the credentials and authorization info you are passing are correct?

Comment: You may want to repeat the instructions @Miguel-F gave but against api.twitter.com as that's where I suspect MonkehTweets is actually making it's requests to. I did look at that using that URL in my demo code above, but it tends to return error codes (400) when you're not authenticated, so I went with the main twitter domain. Try https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json in the demo code and you should get a 400 error code, that'll tell you things are actually OK, as you won't get that far unless the certificates are working

Comment: @barnyr - I updated the URL in my answer to reflect api.twitter.com. Even though surfing to that page will fail, the browser still contains the certificate from the attempt. So it can still be exported using the steps above.

Comment: I installed the api.twitter.com certificate as well and then verified that it's fine - again using the instructions above. Unfortunately I still get the same error: http://d.pr/i/aTqb

Comment: In the meantime, I used [this little trick](http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-rss-feeds/27931/) to create an RSS feed using Google Scripts, which I then query using a simple CFHTTP. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

MonkehTweets uses CFHTTP (in httpOAuthCall in base.cfc) so can you try running this on your server:

```
<cfhttp url="https://twitter.com/">
</cfhttp>
```

That'll tell you if it's a straightforward certificate problem with your CF/JVM setup.

If the call above fails, you can add the certificates [using these instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html). Alternatively, you can try the [JSafe code listed here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/1/12/Diagnosing-a-CFHTTP-issue--peer-not-authenticated) although you'd want to be sure of what it's doing before implementing it in production.

Comment: You are right - I get the same error when I run that simple https request. I tried the JSafe code from Raymond's site but couldn't get it to work on my site. I guess I will need to install the certificate. Anyone have any specific instructions for Twitter's? Note: I am using CF v9.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with monkehTweets and ColdFusion on a CF9 box.

I updated the server with the latest hotfixes then updated the JVM.

Once that was done, everything worked fine.

For me, it boiled down to a JVM issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import your certificate in your coldfusion cacerts:

keytool -importcert -v -alias twitter -file C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\lib\security\twitter.cer -keystore **C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\lib\security\cacerts** -storepass changeit

It worked for me :)